# Populate other properties with a property

Tags: episerver, episerver-6-r2

I have very recently been assigned to an EPiServer project. I'm .Net developer however, I had never had a pleasure of actually working with ES.

I have been given a task of creating a soft "integration" with SoundCloud. Our users would like to copy/paste URL to a SoundCloud song - which then I can use their API to actually get all information of the audio. (title, description, tags etc).

So what I have created so far

- SoundcloudPageType (contains simple properties like title, description, duration etc.)
- I have written little POC for Soundcloud API that gets me all information and deserializes it into object.

What I need now is a bridge between those two. I thought that creating something like "PageLinkReference" where you can click [...] button which would then ask you for "URL to SoundCloud audio", once person enters that I would do a REST api call to pre-populate all other properties on the page.

Now, this is just an idea. I would like to run it past you guys to see if

1. It is possible.
2. What is the best way of doing this and are there any tutorials that do something similar.

I do not want to hack and slash my way through EPiServer but to utilise what EPiServer might already provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a short string property to the SoundcloudPageType and let the users paste into that field.

If you are using PageTypeBuilder something like this:

```
[PageTypeProperty(
        EditCaption = "Soundcloud Url",
        Type = typeof(PropertyString),
        SortOrder = 2010,
        UniqueValuePerLanguage = false,
        Searchable = true)]
public virtual string SoundcloudUrl { get; set; }
```

Then you could either fetch "on request" or fetch and store (easiest on other properties you've added) in one of EPi's save events. Take a look at Joel's article of common patterns when integrating with EPi:

http://joelabrahamsson.com/episerver-integration-patterns/

Comment: Is there a hook or a method I can override on my page type, something like "OnSave" so that I can use that URL and make a call while saving a page in admin to populate all fields?

Comment: Yes, in your case attach the same method to events CreatedPage and SavedPage. Here's one example of how to do it: http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Anders-Hattestad/Dates/2011/2/Auto-create-sub-pages-when-a-page-is-created/

Comment: I have had a play around with DataFactory.Instnance events and none of the events seem to be called right before the page is saved so that I can modify fields before they get saved.

Comment: Did you try "SavingPage" and "CreatingPage"? Thinking more I was probabaly wrong suggesting CreatedPage and SavedPage, but if you use those you are sure to have the new PageReference available if you need it - you need to re-save the page in the event in that case though. http://www.dodavinkeln.se/post/2011/11/14/always-check-if-epage-is-null-in-datafactory-events.aspx

Comment: Sorry that i took so long to come back to you. I have had issues when creating "saving" event because if I change something I need to re trigger save which then creates a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the oEmbed dynamic content plugin, which should support soundcloud

http://nuget.episerver.com/en/?search=oembed&sort=MostDownloads&page=1&pageSize=10

Comment: Very interesting idea. Sadly I need a page type (as I need keep the record of each of songs.